# UITabBarController opens and turns into black Screen in iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios13, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a application flow

first `presentviewController` -> `pushViewController` -> `PushViewController` -> click button action Showing TabBarContorller which in .present(manner)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
let tabBarController = TabBarController.instantiate()
tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(tabBarController, animated: true)
}
```

Application works fine in iOS 11.  When running on iOS 13 its show black Screen

Well I guess if you present of push and then present I guess this make no difference with the application.

Your Inputs are highlight appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share code for `TabBarController`, Also attach image getting related issue.

Comment: you can try this tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen